# Adding ignore case in URL rewriting in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am using following web.config entry for url rewriting to remove .aspx extension.

```
<rewrite url="~/(.+)" to="~/$1.aspx" />
```

The problem I am getting here is if I have any image on page, it assigns .aspx extension to image. 
Also if I tried to access my site like http://exmaple.com, it get redirected to http://exmaple.com/default.aspx.aspx.

I want to know if there is any way to add ignore case in web.config.

Comment: Can you post what you've done to setup url rewriting?

Comment: I have used code from link http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx, Approach 3: Using an HttpModule to Perform Extension-Less URL Rewriting with IIS7

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite should look something like this, to remove .aspx

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="RewriteASPX">
            <match url="(.*)" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```